# JS Fiddle JSON/ECHO returning empty object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am learning ajax, jquery and json.

I have the following JS Fiddle that is sending a request to the JSON/ECHO and the response is an empty object. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/deandalby/7a2t0eb5/3/

```
var saveUrl = "http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json/";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#saveButton").click(function () {
        Save();
    });
});

function GetPersonDetails() {
    var arrayx = $(":input").serializeArray();
    var json = {};
    jQuery.each(arrayx, function () {
        json[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    writeToDom('Formatted JSON', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));

    return json;
}

function Save() {
    var data = GetPersonDetails();

    $.ajax({
      url: saveUrl,
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      success: function (response) {    
        writeToDom('Plain Response', JSON.stringify(response));
        writeToDom('Formatted Response', JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
      },
      error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
      },
      complete: function () {
        writeToDom("complete", "");
      }
    });
}

function writeToDom(title, content) {
    $("form").append("<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>" + title + ":</div><div><pre>" + content + "</pre></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get  jsfiddle `echo` ajax working you have to send the data as a string. In addition the path `/echo/json/` will look for a post key `json` and the string will be the value

Change

```
var data = GetPersonDetails();
```

To

```
var data = {json: JSON.stringify(GetPersonDetails())};
```

If you were working with html it would be:

```
var data ={ html:'<p>Some text</p>'};
```

And the path would be `/echo/html/`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7a2t0eb5/4/)**</kbd>